# ¿Cómo pasar archivos de una lista txt a una carpeta en Bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Pues la tarea parece sencilla pero no logro que trabaje, tengo una carpeta con muchos archivos y tengo una lista que contiene los archivos que quiero, que están dentro de esa carpeta.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=10
i=1

mkdir -p Dir

while (( $i < $n))
do
    var=$(awk NR==$i list.txt)
    cp "$var" ~/Documents/User/Dir
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

me arroja el error
cp: no se puede efectuar 'stat' sobre 'archivo.pdbqt'$'\r': No existe el archivo o el directorio

Estoy ejecutando el script desde la carpeta que contiene todos los archivos, ya revisé que el nombre del archivo esté correctamente escrito en el listado list.txt y si existe el directorio de hecho lo creo con mkdir desde el principio, ojalá alguien sepa como hacer esto.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tu lista tiene el formato de fin
de línea de Windows y debería ser Unix.

Esto elimina el retorno de carro (`\r`) de tu archivo:
`sed -i 's/\r$//' list.txt`

Fuente: [How do I fix “$'\r': command not found” errors running Bash scripts in WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl)

La mayoría de los editores de texto permiten cambiar esto.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo complementando lo que acertadamente dijo @ariadne-cortéz, te sugiero que cambies tu script de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly directorio=/directorio/dir
readonly archivos=./archivos.txt

mkdir -p "$directorio"

awk -v inicio=1 -v fin=5 'NR>inicio && NR<fin' "$archivos" \
    | xargs -P 0 -I {} cp "{}" "$directorio"
```

De esta manera, sólo tendrás que operar con las variables de `awk` y tu código se verá reducido y mejor estructurado y mantenible.

Dentro del archivo `archivos.txt` se encuentra la lista de archivos a mover, y el rango es exclusivo. Así que, cuando pones 1 y 5, como resultado dentrás los archivos desde el segundo renglón hasta el cuarto.

Por ejemplo, para probar la salida, no voy a ejecutar el `cp`, sino un echo al comando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]